# Convert invalid json into valid json in php

Tags: php, json

I am saving some values in database via api(So I can not modify it manually)

When I get back it from database, the json value is not in valid form. I do not want to modify each value in database. I want something in php which can convert that into valid format.

Something like this in my db:

```
$invalid='{
    "response": {

                "id": "16"",  <--------------------- Invalid Format(It can be for any key)
                "event_name": "testing",
                "image": "images/Penguins.jpg",
                "event_date": "2014-12-13",
                "event_time": "02:10",
                "time_interval": "4",
                "location": "mohali",
                "event_type": "Rock",
                "detail": "sfdsf fgf ghb\t",
                "delivery": "dggh fghgfh\t\t",
                "status": "1"
            }
           }';
```

So how can I convert it in valid json by php like this:

```
$invalid='{
    "response": {

                "id": "16",  <--------------------- valid Format
                "event_name": "testing",
                "image": "images/Penguins.jpg",
                "event_date": "2014-12-13",
                "event_time": "02:10",
                "time_interval": "4",
                "location": "mohali",
                "event_type": "Rock",
                "detail": "sfdsf fgf ghb\t",
                "delivery": "dggh fghgfh\t\t",
                "status": "1"
            }
           }';
```

Comment: To clarify - the extra quotes actually exist in the database, correct?

Comment: Why not just change the reason for the extra `"` rather than having to find a way to remove it? Build a temporary php script to edit every input save on the database and change the file that adds the extra `"`

Comment: yes @ Benjamin............

Comment: Is there any reason you do not want to modify those values so they are correct?

Comment: Writing code to make good on something else that's broken is a fool's game. Unless you have some overwhelmingly powerful reason to do otherwise, fix the database.

Comment: It is coming from api in broken form, So I have to modify these in db? @ Hobo Sapiens

Comment: Do you know where this extra `"` is coming from? Is it being added while saving data to the database or while getting the data from the database? Only you know since you can see your own php. We can only see what you display.

Comment: I will take that as a no since you haven't bothered to answer. I wish you luck fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

For this exact case, this will do:

```
<?php
$invalid='{
  "response": {        
    "id": "16"", 
    "event_name": "testing",
    "image": "images/Penguins.jpg",
    "event_date": "2014-12-13",
    "event_time": "02:10",
    "time_interval": "4",
    "location": "",
    "event_type": "Rock"",
    "detail": "sfdsf fgf ghb\t",
    "delivery": "dggh fghgfh\t\t",
    "status": "1""
  },
  "bar":{ "test": ""
  }
}';
$invalid = explode("\n",$invalid);
foreach($invalid as $idx => &$line) {
  $num = 0;
  for($z=0;$z<strlen($line);++$z) {
    $ch = $line[$z];
    if($ch == "\\") {
      ++$z;
    } else if($ch == '"') {
      ++$num;
      $last_pos = $z;
    }
  }
  if($num % 2 == 1) {
    $line[$last_pos] = ' ';
  }             
}       
$valid = implode("\n",$invalid);
print_r($valid);
```

Output:

```
{
  "response": {        
    "id": "16" , 
    "event_name": "testing",
    "image": "images/Penguins.jpg",
    "event_date": "2014-12-13",
    "event_time": "02:10",
    "time_interval": "4",
    "location": "",
    "event_type": "Rock" ,
    "detail": "sfdsf fgf ghb\t",
    "delivery": "dggh fghgfh\t\t",
    "status": "1" 
  },
  "bar":{ "test": ""
  }
}
```

But it's really recommended to fix the data on the database and the form/code that produce those invalid `JSON` ^^

Answer (score -2):

In what ways can it be invalid? If it's only the existence of double quotes just use preg_replace:

```
$valid = preg_replace('/""/','"',$invalid);
```

Comment: `"detail": "",` would be changed to `"detail": ",` which is incorrect